# flutter firebase otp verification

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

We have developed an app in flutter. The app is using firebase otp for authentication.

When we use safety net then the OTP has verified automatically. However, playstore is throwing a warning that SafetyNet is deprecated and we need to switch to play integrity.

We could not remove safetynet from the firebase project so we created another project and instead used play integrity as recommended by playstore. However, the otp is no longer verified automatically.

If we start using safetynet, it works but does not work with play integrity. Can someone please suggest how to fix this?

```
firebase_core: ^1.17.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.18
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
```

Another thing worth noting is that earlier, the app was sending otp and auto verifying on debug mode. However, ever since we have submitted our app to playstore and it is under review, the otp is no longer auto verifying on debug version as well. We are not sure if it has anything to do with the app being under review.

The otp message that we are getting also something like below

34567 is your verification code for com.bla.bla(unreviewed)

I will appreciate if someone could guide us in the right direction.

Comment: have you found a solution there?

Comment: We found the solution but did not implement it. Basically, it requires you to keep the app name/title to less than 13 characters which we did not want. For the time being, we are manually verifying the code. Maybe there is a new fix now but this information is a few months old.